# How to output a random string from an array of string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, random

How to output a random string from a given array of string or from a list in Kotlin

```
var arr = arrayOf("People", "Are", "Awesome")
```

Comment: You can make it even randomly Array like: ```var arr = arrayOf("People", "Are", "Awesome").random()``` then ```println(arr)```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the random function: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val arr = arrayOf("People", "Are", "Awesome")
  println(arr.random())
}
```